# How can I get substring or 2 words from the list on matching text?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a list where all the company name is there

```
organizations={'mahindra & mahindra','atametica','cognizant Technology','Tata Cosultancy Services'}
```

I have a text where I have 1 or 2 company names and I want to extract those company names from the organizations.
example:

```
text = 'XXX has worked in Tata Consultancy Services and currently working in cognizant technology.He has experience in Java Technology as well'
```

How can I fetch company from the text.

Comment: Do you want to extract only the company names carried in `organizations` object of yours? Otherwise, it would be huge.

Comment: @Nitish, if the answer posted below helped, you may accept it by clicking on the tick sign beside it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

OP: *How can I fetch company from the text.*

That would be complex, the other way around would be easier and faster:

You could iterate over the `organisations` and check if any of them exists in the `text` using `in`:

```
organizations = ['mahindra & mahindra','atametica','cognizant Technology','Tata Cosultancy Services']

text = 'XXX has worked in Tata Cosultancy Services and currently working in cognizant technology.He has experience in Java Technology as well'

for org in organizations:
    if org.lower() in text.lower():
        print(org)
```

**EDIT:**

To get all the organisation, use a string comparison with `.lower()` for case insensitive texts.

**EDIT 2:**

Using `re`:

```
import re
for org in organizations:
    if re.search(org, text, re.IGNORECASE):
        print(org)
```

OUTPUT:

```
cognizant Technology
Tata Cosultancy Services
```

**EDIT 3:**

Considering a situation where the element in the `list` exists in the `text` but only partially. You could use the word search using `regex` i.e.

```
organizations = ['mahindra & mahindra','atametica','cognizant Technology','Tata Cosultancy Services', 'nitor']

text = 'XXX has worked in Tata Cosultancy Services and currently working in cognizant technology.He has experience in Java Technology as well as monitor'


import re
for org in organizations:
    if re.search('\\b' +org+ '\\b', text, re.IGNORECASE):
        print(org)
```

OUTPUT:

```
cognizant Technology
Tata Cosultancy Services
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I have done it already.I need both company names like tata consultancy services and cognizant technology

Comment: @Nitish fixed, using `.lower()`

Comment: Thanks for this,but if I wan to extract bank of america this is showing only bank and for other object as well it is happening same.

Comment: @Nitish there is no `bank of america` in the `text` or the `organisation` list.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.I rephrase my query

I need to extract organizations from the resumes that is in text format.I have created a corpus of different companies.Now when I extract the organization on the basis of matching of text and organization corpus. if a single string it is showing correctly but when it comes to 2 or more words organization it shows only first word of it.I hope you understand my issues.

Comment: text = "Develop primary sales and secondary sales dashboard. 
Interact with business users at various locations and understand the requirement and develop/modify reports. 
 Work on CRs post deployment and support. Monitor the scheduled reload and maintain the same. "......so it is extracting "nitor" an organization which is acually exist in corpus but in text it is monitor.

Comment: @Nitish You should have added that in your question. However, Check edit 3, I have added that check, PS. if it helps, you may mark the answer by clicking on the tick sign beside it to accept it. cheers